# Hand soap made with milk as an ingredient, and eating meat

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk

If one uses a [hand-soap that is made with milk](https://web.archive.org/web/20220707033740/https://www.superdrug.com/toiletries/washing-bathing/hand-wash/palmolive-liquid-hand-soap-milk-and-honey-300ml/p/730341), is one allowed to proceed to eat meat with their hands, like a chicken drumstick?

Is it too little a proportion, or too far removed from *derech achila* (the way of eating, in a halachic sense) to be considered and issue or should we be machmir/strict?

Comment: Are you asking about eating with soapy hands, (say, what?) or after you've rinsed off the soap and dried your hands? (IOW words, if you dip your hand into the milk jug, can you eat your pulka after washing your hands?)

Comment: this is not edible 'milk'. noten taam lifgam.

Comment: @DannySchoemann with hand soap, they design it so that the ta'am remains on your hands even after washing off the substance

Comment: If the lactic acid is added to a shampoo, would the amount of soap not make it permissible? [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De'ah 95:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.95.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) see also [I bought shampoo that contains lactic acid and stearates](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/i-bought-shampoo-that-contains-lactic-acid-and-stearates-i-heard-that-lactic-acid-can-be-derived-from-milk-and-stearates-may-be-derived-from-animal-oil-am-i-permitted-to-use-this-shampoo-or-is-ther/)

Comment: Even if we assumed this were a problem the soap would have been washed off before you touched the meat

Comment: @Shmuel see 87:6, Rama machmir l'chatchila not to use a kli for shampoo even though the issur is lifgam. See Taz there, quoting Maharil about borit

Comment: @RabbiKaii "they design so the ta'am remains on your hands" - are you maybe confusing taste and smell? Maybe the smell remains on your hands but there is no quantity of milk on your hands

Comment: @mbloch Good point! I actually doubt the taste-on-tongue is designed to stay. Fair enough. Generally (if not necessarily halachically) taste is composed of a combination of sensation on the tongue combined with sensation in the nose. Also, if the smell remains, it makes sense to suspect the "taste" (on the tongue) remains as well, although I admit I'd have to prove that. Would be glad to hear a sourced answer to deal with these 2 issues.